# Variance and co-variance of bivariate multinomial distribution

Tags: probability, covariance, multinomial-distribution

Suppose we have two discrete variable $(X,Y)$, where $X$ takes values $x_i, i=1,2,...,k$ and $Y$ takes values $y_j,j=1,2,...,l$.

Suppose we have total $n$ samples of $(X,Y)$, let random variable $Z_{ij}$ the number of samples with $X=x_i,Y=y_j$.

My question is how to compute $\mathrm{Var}(Z_{ij})$ and $\mathrm{Cov}(Z_{i_1,j},Z_{i_2,j})$.

I think of three solutions, however, they give contradictive answers, which is my major confusion.

**Solution-1**

The random vector $\mathbf{Z}=[Z_{ij}]_{i=1,2,...,k; j=1,2,...,l}$ follows a multinomial distribution with parameters $(n,\{p(x_i,y_j)\}_{i=1,2,...,k; j=1,2,...,l})$.

So, we have $\mathrm{E}(Z_{ij})=np(x_i,x_j)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Z_{ij})=np(x_i,y_j)(1-p(x_i,y_j))$.

**Solution-2**

The random vector $\mathbf{Z}=[Z_{ij}]_{\text{fixed} \, i; j=1,2,...,l}$ follows a multinomial distribution with parameters $(n_{i:},\{p(y_j|x_i)\}_{\text{fixed} \, i; j=1,2,...,l})$, where $n_{i:}$ is the number of samples with $X=x_i$.

So, we have $\mathrm{E}(Z_{ij})=n_{i:}p(y_j|x_i)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Z_{ij})=n_{i:}p(y_j|x_i)(1-p(y_j|x_i))$.

**Solution-3**

The random vector $\mathbf{Z}=[Z_{ij}]_{i=1,2,...,k; \text{fixed} \, j}$ follows a multinomial distribution with parameters $(n_{:j},\{p(x_i|y_j)\}_{i=1,2,...,k; \text{fixed} \, j})$, where $n_{:j}$ is the number of samples with $Y=y_j$.

So, we have $\mathrm{E}(Z_{ij})=n_{:j}p(x_i|y_j)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Z_{ij})=n_{:j}p(x_i|y_j)(1-p(x_i|y_j))$.

If Solution-1,2,3 are correct, then we have $p(x_i,y_j)=p(x_i|y_j)=p(y_j|x_i)$, which is apparently wrong.

Can anyone points out which part of my solutions is wrong? What's the correct answer?

P.S. My objective is to get the MLE estimator and its co-variance matrix of the parameter $[p(y_j|x_1),...,p(y_j|x_k)]$ for some fixed $j$.

Comment: I see no problems with Solution-1. In Solution-2,3 you are considering conditional distributions. For example, $n_{:j}p(x_i|y_j)$ is not the expectation of $Z_{ij}$. Instead it seems to be the conditional expectation of $Z_{ij}$ given $n_{:j}$.

Comment: Adding to my comment: With $E[Z_{ij}|n_{:j}]=n_{:j}p(x_i|y_j)$ you find that $E[Z_{ij}]=E[E[Z_{ij}|n_{:j}]]=E[n_{:j}]p(x_i|y_j)=np(y_j)p(x_i|y_j)=np(x_i,y_j)$. So Solution-3 does actually result in the same conclusion as Solution-1. Solution-2 is of course similar.

Comment: You are right! Add to your comment (Solution-2/3 give the same variance/co-variance as Solution-1): with $E(Z_{ij}|n_{:j})=n_{:j}p(x_i|y_j)$ and $Var(Z_{ij}|n_{:j})=n_{:j}p(x_i|y_j)(1-p(x_i|y_j))$ and the law of total variance $Var(Y)=E(Var(Y|X))+Var(E(Y|X))$, we can derive $Var(Z_{ij})=E(Var(Z_{ij}|n_{:j}))+Var(E(Z_{ij}|n_{:j}))=np(y_j)p(x_i|y_j)(1-p(x_i|y_j))+p^2(x_i|y_j)np(y_j)(1-p(y_j))=np(x_i,y_j)(1-p(x_i,y_j))$, which is the same result as Solution-1.

Comment: @jakobdt. So, I can use $\hat{p}(y_j|x_i):=\frac{Z_{ij}}{n_{i:}}$ as a consistent estimator of $p(y_j|x_i)$, because we have $E[\frac{Z_{ij}}{n_{i:}}]=E[E[\frac{Z_{ij}}{n_{i:}}|n_{i:}]]=E[\frac{n_i:p(y_j|x_i)}{n_i:}]=p(y_j|x_i)$. Similarly, we have the variance of our estimator below, right? $\mathrm{Var}[\hat{p}(y_j|x_i)]=\mathrm{Var}[\frac{Z_{ij}}{n_{i:}}]=E[\mathrm{Var}[\frac{Z_{ij}}{n_{i:}}|n_{i:}]]+\mathrm{Var}[E[\frac{Z_{ij}}{n_{i:}}|n_{i:}]]=E[n_{i:}p(y_j|x_i)(1-p(y_j|x_i))]+\mathrm{Var}[p(y_j|x_i)]=np(x_i)p(y_j|x_i)(1-p(y_j|x_i))$

Comment: Do you know how to compute the co-variance $\mathrm{Cov}[\hat{p}(y_j|x_{i_1}),\hat{p}(y_j|x_{i_2})]$ for a fixed $j$ and some $i_1,i_2$? Many thanks.

Comment: It's not something I've done before so I wouldn't expect to be any better than you at it.